# Ansible archive is not adding certain path to the archive

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible

I have the folder structure below:

```
/ansible
/shared
/logic
     /business
          /src
              /folder_1
              /folder_2
     /infrastructure
          /run.sh
```

In **/ansible** folder, I have an ansible task that does the following:

```yaml
- name: Package Lambda code source
  archive:
    path:
    - ../business/src/{{ item }}
    - ../../shared
    dest: "{{ item }}.zip"
    exclude_path:
    - ../logic/business/src/
    format: zip
  loop: 
    - folder_1
    - folder_2
```

Where the **run.sh** file is the one running the Ansible task.
The output of the archive is the following:

```
/infrastructure/folder_1.zip
/infrastructure/folder_2.zip
```

But the issue is that the content of the zip folder does only contain the elements under **business/src** but not the **shared** folder. If I extract the content of the zip file, I can clearly see the shared folder inside. This issue is preventing me from deploying Lambda function as it is considering the folder inside the zip file empty.
Even the *exclude_path* is not working.

Comment: Please review your question because none of the path in you task actually make sense compared to your description and the file tree you have pasted. Consider using the `tree` command for this rather than creating it manually. At this point no one can guess if your tree contains copy/paste error or if your paths are pointing to nowhere.

Comment: From the docs: [_exclude_path: Remote **absolute** path, glob, or list of paths or globs for the file or files to exclude from path list and glob expansion._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html)

Comment: So, in short you cannot do `../this_is_the_parent_dir_of_my_playbook`, as this is a _relative_ path and not an **absolute** one.

Comment: @Zeitounator I reviewed my question and the paths are correct, I did not use tree as some of the structures must remain confidential so I posted the folders that I needed/used during the implementation.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I will re-check this again, thank you.

Comment: @Zeitounator was actually pointing at the mismatch between the location of the _shared_ folder and your usage of `../../shared` that does not seems to make sense.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I got your point but because of *run.sh* located under the *infrastructure* folder that is running Ansible commands, that's why I was referencing to the shared folder in this way ```../../shared```

Comment: `I did not use tree as some of the structures must remain confidential` <= you would be amazed of all the possibilities to meet those kind of requirements and all the possibilities offered by the tool by typing `man tree`. Beside that, even a plain unfiltered `tree` output is very easy to cleanup and better than a hand crafted structure with possible mistakes. Lastly, you are supposed to give a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve) and it was quite easy to make that structure without any garbage/unwanted content in e.g. your `/tmp` folder.

Comment: @Zeitounator excuse my beginner knowledge :)

Comment: @OumaymaAmri ooooh. I see, but that's not how it works, the context of the shell command running `ansible-playbook` and the context of Ansible running the playbook are two different things. Mainly because Ansible is meant to run on remote nodes, where the folder hierarchy might be totally different from the controller. So, when using relative path in an Ansible playbook, they will either be relative to the playbook (when local action are involved) or should be absolute.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I totally agree with you but unfortunately, this is the structure that I found and I should deal with, without changing it...

Comment: @OumaymaAmri this is not an issue with the hierarchy of your folders, but an issue with your comprehension of what path are relative to for Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the documentation, both `path` and `exclude_path` should be **absolute** path.

> `exclude_path`: Remote absolute path, glob, or list of paths or globs for the file or files to exclude from path list and glob expansion.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html#parameter-exclude_path*</sup>

> `path`: Remote absolute path, glob, or list of paths or globs for the file or files to compress or archive.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html#parameter-path*</sup>

In order to get an absolute path based on the path of a playbook, you can use the [special variable `playbook_dir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and the filter [`dirname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) to get its parent folder.

So, this task should more accurately follow what the documentation indicates — given that your provided folder hierarchy is correct:

```yaml
- name: Package Lambda code source
  archive:
    path:
    - {{ playbook_dir | dirname }}/logic/business/src/{{ item }}
    - {{ playbook_dir | dirname }}/shared
    dest: "{{ item }}.zip"
    exclude_path:
    - {{ playbook_dir | dirname }}/logic/business/src/
    format: zip
  loop: 
    - folder_1
    - folder_2
```