# Why is my Ansible script not archiving files with its topmost directory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template, ansible-awx, ansible-filter

I am writing an Ansible script to archive files (with its directory structure) based on type of files, number of days before they got created etc. To do selection of type of files, I am using `find` command and then putting all files inside list (using `set_fact` module). After that I am giving this list to Archive module to `archive`.

But my issue is, it is always not considering top most directory which I am giving in source to archive it at destination.

```yaml
tasks:

  - name: Recursively find directories/files which are older than given days
    find:
       paths: "{{ source }}"
       file_type: any
       patterns: "{{ type_file }}"
       age: "{{ days }}d"
       recurse: true
    register: output
  
  - block:

     - name: Archiving files/directories
       set_fact:
         files_to_archive: "{{ files_to_archive|default([]) + [ item.path ] }}"
       with_items: "{{ output.files }}"

     - archive:
         path: "{{ files_to_archive }}"
         dest: "{{ destination }}/backup.tar.gz"
         format: gz
         force_archive: yes
```

Lets say I have directory `Dfile`

```
Dfile
└── efile
    ├── 1.sh
    ├── 2.sh
    └── kfile
        └── mfile
            ├── 1.txt
            └── 2.txt
```

In this I want to archive all `*.sh` files. So at destination output is coming like this

```
efile
    ├── 1.sh
    ├── 2.sh
```

that means it is removing `Dfile` as top most directory.

Can anyone please tell what is going wrong in this Ansible script? I need output like this at destination

```
Dfile
└── efile
    ├── 1.sh
    ├── 2.sh
```

Comment: "_Why is my Ansible script not archiving files with its topmost directory?_" maybe you are running from within folder `DFile`. Furthermore, the content of variable `source` is not provided, maybe it is a relative path.

Comment: @ U880D for source I am giving path like -  /home/ansible/Dfile   .  Dfile is folder from where files have to be archived from managed machine.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as

**How to enforce an absolute path in files archived via Ansible `archive` module? How to make `archive` module behave similar to the `tar` command?**

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test.example.com
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Recursively find directories/files which are older than given days
    find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/toarchive"
      file_type: file
      patterns: "*.sh"
      age: "0d"
      recurse: true
    register: output

  - name: Archiving files/directories
    set_fact:
      files_to_archive: "{{ files_to_archive | default([]) + [ item.path ] }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ item.path }}"
    loop: "{{ output.files }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ files_to_archive }}"

  - archive:
      path: "{{ files_to_archive }}"
      dest: "backup.tar.gz"
      format: gz
      force_archive: true

  - archive:
      path: "{{ files_to_archive }}"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/backup.tar.gz"
      format: gz
      force_archive: true
```

outputing with absolute paths

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - /home/ansible-user/test/toarchive/2.sh
  - /home/ansible-user/test/toarchive/3.sh
  - /home/ansible-user/test/toarchive/1.sh
```

and an archive file checked via [How to view specific path inside `tar.gz`?](https://superuser.com/q/1337229/754490), gave a result of

```sh
~/test$ tar tf ../backup.tar.gz
# or
~/test$ tar tf backup.tar.gz
1.sh
2.sh
3.sh
~/test$ tar tf ../backup.tar.gz /home/
# or
~/test$ tar tf backup.tar.gz
tar: /home: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Changing to an example like in [Ansible: `archive` is not adding certain path to the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71118191/6771046), the behavior remained, archives were created without absolute paths, specifically, the root path was in every case missing.

**To Summarize**

Even if able to reproduce the observation I am not sure if it is the expected behavior. One may need to investigate further.

Comment: in your source you have given path "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/toarchive". files were in "toarchive" folder . Now when you unarchived files came as 1.sh,2.sh and 3.sh.  But I want when we unarchive then first folder "toarchive" should come from compressed folder(backup.tar.gz) and under that all .sh files should be present. @U880D

Comment: Right, yes. As I mentioned I was just able to reproduce your result but haven't found a way to make the behavior as expected. More worse, I don't get any absolute path or path into the archive.

Comment: yeah that's my pain @U880D, I want absolute path or atleast if giving /home/test  as source directory name then in compressed folder directory starting from "test" should be present. I dont know what is going wrong and if there is any other way to acheive same result what I want.

Comment: As mentioned I am not sure if this is the expected behavior, so, there might be nothing wrong and maybe it will not be possible to achieve the result in that way. Unless you are not going to archive the whole folder tree and remove unnecessary files afterwards.